Identify humongous fold-out crossword from the 80's
My father says he used to love crosswords until he was given one in high school (in 1985) that was so big he got tired and gave up. It was a booklet-thick paper which folded out to reveal the whole board. He claims there were thousands of clues, though that may be hyperbolic or an exaggeration of memory. It would have been in English and he was in the United States. However, as the crossword was a present, it may have been bought from elsewhere.
Since this was the 80's it can't be the NYT Super Mega crossword; that started in 2016. Search results for "gigantic crossword" or "crossword with thousands of clues" or similar are clogged with irrelevant crossword clue answers.
Can a likely candidate for this crossword be identified? Ideally answers would include a picture. I'm genuinely unsure of whether there are multiple possibilities ("giant crossword" cannot be a unique idea) but hopefully at least the time period lets it be narrowed down.

I seem to remember seeing something along those lines. A search on "largest crossword puzzle in the world" brings up this page. In the table of largest crossword puzzles are these possible, English language listings:



Squares
Clues
Language
Author, where published





6,334
English
Robert M. Stilgenbauer (USA), constructed in 7 years, published as a booklet in 1949 by Things Original, Los Angeles



12,308
English
Stephen Robinson, published by Onsworld Ltd, Stamford on 22 October 1979, measured 1.72 sq metres


>91,000
28,000
English
published in a box by Herbko (possibly this one)




That last one is very interesting! Do you know when it was published?

@bobble Pretty sure I had this one! Unless I'm mistaken, I was given it as a gift in about 2014-15 so it's at least that old... Never managed to finish it - we had a (small) fire that caused it to be thrown away, sadly...

This site claimed it broke the "1996 Guinness World Record," which puts it firmly after 1985 when my dad would have received it. The Robinson one looks more likely then.
